# VBA fill formula up to last row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table `Scanner` with column `Quartile 1 (Q1)`
I wanted to fill the column with this worksheet formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(B27=B8, QUARTILE(J8:J27, 1), ""), "")
```

I used B27=B8 to assure that I am referencing same product name/category to apply Quartile function.

This formula works fine in worksheet, however, I think I need to use VBA to simplify my task everytime additional data has been loaded in the table.

I tried to use below code but gives me runtime error

> '1004' - Application defined or Object defined error.

```
Range("Scanner[Quartile 1 (Q1)]") = "=IFERROR(IF([@ProductName]=R[-19]C[-64], QUARTILE(R[-19]C[-56]:RC[-56], 1), """"), """")"
```

Appreciate if some can help me how to fix this error

Comment: Are your R1C1 references going off-sheet?

Comment: Yes. Formula will be in error till it reaches row 20

Comment: K - that error would mean you're referencing an off-sheet range. Change your R1C1 Relative references so they don't go off-sheet... another way to perform the math so a non-existent range is attempted.

Comment: Seems adding a new column labeling row number reference to product name will do the trick. Thanks for your response

Comment: Tried it and failed.. still need your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue was references was going off-sheet. 
It was resolve by simply changing the formula criteria. I used date as a qualifier. For other case, index might be helpful solution as well.

```
=IF([@date]>DATE(2018,1,29), QUARTILE(J8:J27, 1), "")
```